# Woocommerce: Use Stock Management for different attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to use the Stock Management in Woocommerce. I have some products which use variing attributes (sizes in my case), however, the stock management only lets me enter a anmount for the whole product (eg 11 running Shirts instead of 11 running shirts in size L). Is there any way to use stock management on attributes?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the variable product documentation:](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/variable-product/)

> Each variation may be assigned:
> [...]
>   **Stock quantity** – Stock for the specific variation, or left blank to use the product’s stock settings.

So, set your product as variable product and check "used for variation"  for your size attribute like this:

[image]

Then go on the variation tab and generate a variation for each attribute value. On each variation, you have a checkbox to activate the stock management for this attribute value - if it's not checked, it will use the general product inventory in the inventory tab.

[image]